# facebook open graph for each product

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building an ecommerce site for my project. I want to use open graph in it. I added meta tags in my header page and when copying that link to facebook status. It shows open graph with my site logo. Now I want to show open graph for each product.
For exapmle: 
If `http://localhost/c2c/index.php/init/product/238` this my url for the product and if I copied that link to facebook status then I want opengraph with the image of the product with its title and description. How can i achieve this. Thank you.

Open garph for my site is:

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="Bizbazzar - E-commerce Solution."/>
 <meta property="og:type" content="Ecommerce"/>
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.bizbazzar.com"/>
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.bizbazzar.com.np/content/images/bizbazzar.jpg"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="bizbazzar"/>
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="798589833503780"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="Bizbazzar- The customer to customer business."/>
```

And How to show open graph for each product with the product information like its title and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use foreach loop for every product that you want to link to facebook open graph with the name, description and image of that product as:

```
         <?php if(isset($product_details)) {
       foreach($product_details as $p){ ?>
      <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $p->titles; ?>"/>
      <meta property="og:type" content="Ads Post"/>
      <meta property="og:url" content="<?php ?>"/>
      <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/'.$p->images; ?>"/>
     <meta property="og:site_name" content="bizbazzar"/>
     <meta property="fb:app_id" content="439815212823766"/>
     <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $p->description; ?>"/>
       <?php } }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the OpenGraph object type `product` which can contain a lot of product-specific details:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/product/

If you just want the asic stuff, like image, title and description, just alter your code in a way that you fill the content dynamically (e.g. from your product database).

Example:

```
 <meta property="og:title" content="<? echo $db->product->name ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:type" content="product"/>
 <meta property="og:url" content="<? echo http' . (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 's' : '') . '://' . "{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}/{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']} ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:image" content="<? echo $db->product->imageURL ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="bizbazzar"/>
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="798589833503780"/>
 <meta property="og:description" content="<? echo $db->product->description?>"/>
```

Comment: thank you. I will surely give it a try and let you know. THank you alot.

Comment: Do I need to write this code in `product.php` page? . I think meta tag are only used in heading tags and is it okey if i write in `<body>` section.

Comment: Well, this is just sample code! You need to fill in you actual application code for sure. The meta tags belong to the `head` section.

Comment: hi tobi, actually I am getting null on how to do this. How can I specify that product_id, product_name for specific product. I am using codeigniter.